# Need help: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```
import './App.css';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import Header from './Header';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Feed from './Feed';
import { selectUser } from './features/userSlice';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {

  const user = useSelector(selectUser)

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />

      {!user ? (
        <Login />
      ) : (
        <div className="app__body">
          <Sidebar />
          <Feed />
          {/* Widgets */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = userSlice.actions;

// Selectors 
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Can you also share the code of `selectUser`?

Comment: everything looks fine here. issue must be somewhere else.  Does stack trace point specifically on App component?